# Mathematical connection between SZ RSS and VSZ in ps o/p?

Tags: linux, memory, ps

I wanted to know what mathematical connection is there between the SZ, RSS and VSZ output in ps output e.g.

```
ps -p 2363 -o sz,rss,vsz
```

Comment: and the output is?..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`sz` and `vsz` represent the same thing, but `sz` is in page units, while `vsz` is in 1024 byte units.

To get your system's page size, you can use:

```
$ getconf PAGE_SIZE
4096
```

`rss` is the subset of the process's memory that is currently loaded in RAM (in kilobytes). This is necessarily smaller than `vsz`.

So the "mathematical" connections are:

```
vsz * 1024 = sz * page_size
rss <= vsz
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Any idea how %mem is related to rss and sz/vsz?

Comment: @Mat perfect answer, also a great question Mr. abc.