# Find out the total memory allocated for a particular process in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, process, memory

How can I find out the total memory allocated for a particular process in Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you tried ps -aefl and looked at the SZ column?

Comment: What do you mean by “find out the memory allocated”? Do you want to know how much memory the process is using?

Answer (score 17):

Try:

```
pidof bash | xargs ps -o rss,sz,vsz
```

To find the memory usage of your current `bash` shell (assuming you're using `bash`). Change `bash` to whatever you're investigating. If you're after one specific process, simply use on it's own:

```
ps -o rss,sz,vsz <process id>
```

From the `man` page:

`RSS`: resident set size, the non-swapped physical memory that a task has used (in kiloBytes).

`SZ`: size in physical pages of the core image of the process. This includes text, data, and stack space.

`VSZ`: virtual memory size of the process in KiB (1024-byte units).

The `man` page for `ps` will list all the possible arguments to the `-o` option (there are quite a few to choose from). Instead of `-o rss,sz` you could use the BSD style `v` option (no dash) which shows an alternative memory layout.

Comment: Thanks gareth... Are you saying that SZ is the memory allocated for that process?

Comment: There's a good QA [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32534/mathematical-connection-between-sz-rss-and-vsz-in-ps-o-p) that explains the relationship between `RSS`, `SZ` and `VSZ`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `pmap` which shows the memory map of a process:

```
pmap -p pid
```

For more information about it see the man page `man pmap` or have a look at [pmap(1): report memory map of process - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pmap).

Answer (score 0):

> how to find out the total memory allocated for a particular process in ubuntu?

You don't define what is the *memory allocated* for a process, and actually that is a pretty complex question (what about shared memory mappings - see [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) for details; what about POSIX shared memory - see [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) for more; what about some pages in the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache) used for opened files; etc...)

You could use the `/proc/` file system (which BTW is used by `ps`, `pmap`, `top`, `htop` etc....). Read [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for more. In particular for process of pid 1234 you could use `/proc/1234/status`, `/proc/1234/statm`, `/proc/1234/maps` etc... They are all textual pseudo-files (a bit like pipes) that you can see with `cat` (or read *sequentially* inside some program). BTW, from inside a program you might use `/proc/self`  (which is a pseudo symlink), e.g. read sequentially `/proc/self/status` etc...

See also [LinuxAteMyRam](http://linuxatemyram.com/).